# What is the proper way to reference an element inside a SVG file from a HTML file?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to construct a buttons collection for a website. Since the buttons share several properties (colours and effects) I've decided to use SVG. In order to reduce the HTTP requests, I tried to nest several elements and filters inside the same SVG file. The idea is instantiate these elements to construct all the buttons, toggle switches, etc by simply using the <use> tag.

After reading great articles like [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/), [this](https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-with-external-reference-take-2/), and [this](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/) I'm still not being able to do such thing. I found myself stuck. So I decided to simplify the problem as much as I could within the snippet down bellow.

```html
  <style>
    svg,
    img,
    object {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    h3 {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
  </style>


  <h1>Swimming Veggies. The SVG club that's driving me nuts.</h1>

  <h3>This is an inline SVG.</h3>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <g id="pool">
        <rect width="50" height="50" fill="aqua" />
    </g>
    <symbol id="tomato">
        <circle cx="35" cy="35" r="10" fill="tomato" />
    </symbol>
    <g id="orange">
        <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" fill="orange" />
    </g>
</svg>
  <p>Things work as expected here. The &lt;g&gt; elements #pool and #orange show up while the &lt;symbol id="tomato"&gt; doesn't. Great!</p>

  <h3>This is a SVG using &lt;use&gt; to referencing elements from the inline SVG above.</h3>
  <svg style="border: 1px solid black;" width="50" height="50">
    <use xlink:href="#pool"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#tomato"></use>
</svg>
  <p>Note that the &lt;symbol id="tomato"&gt; element shows up here like the g elemet "pool". The "orange" element is NOT being &lt;use&gt;d. Works fine. Expected behaviour.</p>

  <h3>This is a SVG being put as an IMG.</h3>
  <img src="club.svg">
  <p>Works fine to me and the absence of the &lt;symbol id="tomato"&gt; is the expeted behaviour. I don't want to use SVG this way though.</p>
  <p> Unfortunately, IMGUR didn't accept SVGs and I didn't find an image sharing platform that accepts SVG files. The "club.svg" file has the same content as the commented code at the end of this HTML snippet. The SVG file is located ON THE SAME FOLDER of the HTML file. Sorry for the inconvenience :(</p>


  <h3>This is a SVG being put as an OBJECT</h3>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="club.svg"></object>
  <p>This works as expected.</p>
  <p>Again, the "club.svg" file content is shown as a comment inside and at the end of this HTML snippet.</p>


  <h3>An unsuccessful attempt to extract elements from an OBJECT SVG </h3>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="club.svg#tomato"></object>
  <p>The browser is ignoring the "#tomato" after the file name. Is it possible to extract/manipulate elements inside the SVG file this way? If so, how?</p>


  <h3>This is a SVG being put as an external reference.</h3>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="club.svg#pool"></use>
    <use xlink:href="club.svg#tomato"></use>
    <use xlink:href="club.svg#orange"></use>
</svg>
  <p>That would be my preferable way to clone/manipulate elements from an external source (in this case, "club.svg"). Unfortunately, it's not working for me. It's not clonning the element. What am I doing wrong?</p>


  <h3>Here goes the club.svg content (it's commented inside the snippet).</h3>
  <!-- 
Down bellow is the code inside the club.svg file:

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 50 50">

    <g id="pool">
        <rect width="50" height="50" fill="aqua" />
    </g>

    <symbol id="tomato">
        <circle cx="35" cy="35" r="10" fill="tomato" />
    </symbol>

    <g id="orange">
        <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" fill="orange" />
    </g>

</svg>
 -->
```

By the way... I tried to open up the file on Brave, Opera, Chrome and Safari. All of them show the same results.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: There's an example of external <use> here: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectApproved/struct-use-05-b.html

Comment: One thing that I didn't understand and your example helped me figuring out is the absence of the xlink namespace declaration on my SVG file. I read the article bellow and now I've fixed it. The -use- element still not "grabbing" elements by their IDs though. I'll keep looking for what's going on. Thanks for your hint ;) 

 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course